# GMod - Spawning reflective objects breaks cubemaps?

Tags: garrys-mod

Sometimes, in GMod, I'll spawn a prop from the spawnmenu that has a reflective surface, and it will cause all the reflective surfaces to be turned to the default pink/black, checkered texture. It effects brushes, props, weapons, etc. It doesn't happen when I load up the map, just after I spawn some things. Restarting on a new map or restarting GMod entirely usually works. But why is this happening at all?

Comment: Well, cubemaps for maps are compiled up front and then embedded into the BSP.

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, but spawning reflective props sometimes turns the reflections into the checkered texture. I don't know why.